# Rails timer countdown, which doesn't reset after page refreshing

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, timer

I'm creating Rails web application. I want create timer for 15 seconds, which does not reset when I refresh page. I've tried use jQuery countdown from Keith Wood but when I refresh page, timer resets. So, I think I need create timer on backend but I can't imagine how realize this. Can anyone help? There is my timer code below

```
$('#timer_' + auct_id).countdown({until: +15, onTick: function(periods) {
    var seconds_addition;
    if (periods[6] < 10)
        seconds_addition = '0';
    else
        seconds_addition = '';
    $('#timer_' + auct_id).text('0' + periods[5] + ':' +
        seconds_addition + periods[6]);
}});
```

Comment: put that js code as inline.

Comment: You might be having an issue with Turbolinks in Rails. What event is triggering this script?